# Java & Pig - Passing arguments to a pig script with PigServer

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

I have this java program, which executes a pig script in MapReduce mode. Here is the code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.pig.ExecType;
import org.apache.pig.PigServer;
import org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException;


public class pigCV {


public static void main(String args[]){

PigServer pigServer;
try {

Properties props = new Properties();
props.setProperty("fs.default.name", "hdfs://hdfs://localhost:8022");
props.setProperty("mapred.job.tracker", "localhost:8021");

pigServer = new PigServer(ExecType.MAPREDUCE, props);

pigServer.registerScript("Desktop/text_v3.pig");

} 
catch (ExecException e) {   e.printStackTrace(); } 
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

}


}
```

Via the linux command line, I'm able to pass arguments to the pig script with a command like this:

> pig -f "Desktop/text_v3.pig" -param param1=value1 -param2=value2

But with PigServer, I did not find how to do it.

Do you know how to resolve the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: How do you execute this script after registerscript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this version of the `registerScript` method:

```
public void registerScript(String fileName, Map<String,String> params)
```

The java docs explanation is the following: "Register a pig script file. The parameters in the file will be substituted with the values in params."